# Pod deletion policy when scaling down the deployment?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to tell `k8s` to delete the oldest `pods` in the `deployment` first?

For instance I have a `deployment` which consist of 3 pods. I then decided to scale it up by adding 3 more `pods`:

```
kubectl scale deployment some-deployment --replicas=6
```

After finishing my tests I want it to be 3 pods again, so I scale it down:

```
kubectl scale deployment some-deployment --replicas=3
```

Is there a way to configure deployment in a way so that during the scale down process the oldest pods would be removed first? What if I need it the other way around, delete more recent pods first?

Comment: Why do that? All pods in a deployment, by definition, are identical. It should not matter.

Comment: @MarcinRomaszewicz One reason might be to trigger zero down time pod renewal without actually changing the deployment spec. For instance if I changed something in the configMap and needed to reload the app in the pods. Other reason might be if I notice that someone uploaded a different version of an app with exactly the same tag of the docker image (latest), so in this case by scaling down I would like to remove just the more recent pods, restore the image and scale up again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45509). You may find [this related item](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4301) interesting. Currently you are not able to do it. Let's hope it will be fixed soon.